# Hybrid flow: invalid_client

Tags: aurelia, identityserver3

I'm trying to log-in using IdentityServer3 (self hosted) with the hybrid flow, but when the browser tries to connect to http://localhost:44333/core/connect/token I get a 400 Bad Request with a response message like {"error":"invalid_client"}. The request header contains a cookie returned from IdentityServer and the request payload consists of an access_token, a redirecUri, a session_state and a token_type. The server log looks like this:

```
[14:23:20 INF] Creating Hybrid Flow response.
[14:23:20 INF] Creating Implicit Flow response.
[14:23:20 DBG] Creating access token
[14:23:20 DBG] Creating JWT access token
[14:23:20 DBG] Creating identity token
[14:23:20 INF] Getting claims for identity token for subject: Petter
[14:23:20 DBG] Creating JWT identity token
[14:23:20 DBG] Adding client nettweb to client list cookie for subject Petter
[14:23:20 INF] Redirecting to: http://localhost:9000
[14:23:20 INF] CORS request made for path: /connect/token from origin: http://localhost:9000
[14:23:20 INF] Client list checked and origin: http://localhost:9000 is allowed
[14:23:20 INF] CorsPolicyService allowed origin
[14:23:20 INF] Start token request
[14:23:20 DBG] Start client validation
[14:23:20 DBG] Start parsing Basic Authentication secret
[14:23:20 DBG] Start parsing for secret in post body
[14:23:20 DBG] No secret in post body found
[14:23:20 DBG] Start parsing for X.509 certificate
[14:23:20 DBG] client_id is not found in post body
[14:23:20 INF] Parser found no secret
[14:23:20 INF] No client secret found
[14:23:20 INF] End token request
[14:23:20 INF] Returning error: invalid_client
```

Parsing the access token at jwt.io reveals that client_id is indeed part of the payload, so I am a bit at loss as to why IdSrvr complains.

The client setup is:

```
var config = {
    endpoint: 'auth',
    configureEndpoints: ['auth'],
    baseUrl: 'connect/token',
    token_name: 'id_token',
    profileUrl: '/connect/userinfo',
    unlinkUrl: '/connect/endsession',
    logoutRedirect: '/',
    loginRedirect: '#/',
    providers: {
        identityServer: {
            name: 'Test IdP',
            authorizationEndpoint: 'http://localhost:44333/core/connect/authorize',
            logoutEndpoint: 'http://localhost:44333/core/connect/logout',
            redirectUri: window.location.origin || window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host,
            scope: ['openid', 'profile', 'roles', 'resourceaccess'],
            responseType: 'code id_token token',
            scopePrefix: '',
            scopeDelimiter: ' ',
            requiredUrlParams: ['scope', 'nonce', 'resource'],
            optionalUrlParams: ['display'],
            state: 'session_state',
            oauthType: '2.0',
            clientId: 'testclient',
            clientSecret: 'gsQSM334plJvWpiqKXJvhWcTXsL4Dp7dWIUzcFhappM=',
            flow: 'hybrid',
            nonce: function() {
                var val = ((Date.now() + Math.random()) * Math.random()).toString().replace(".", "");
                return encodeURIComponent(val);
            },
            popupOptions: {width: 452, height: 633},
        }
    }
}

export default config;
```

where 'auth' refers to `http://localhost:44333/core/`

(client js library used: aurelia-authentication)

TIA

Comment: You should inspect the token request and see what gets sent over. Browser connecting to /token endpoint at all sounds like an anti-pattern, bt that is the client library issue. Token endpoint should be used on the back end and not from the browser, and having to push the client secret to the browser is clearly a bad idea.

Comment: Re: "Browser connecting to /token endpoint at all sounds like an anti-pattern, bt that is the client library issue". Yes it is, there's little I can do about it. However, I switched to using the implicit flow and things are working as expected.